# How to show read-only in a view of InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

1. I have a InfoPath form with two different views first view is having title, team name and notes1 and a submit button.
2. Once user submits the form for first time it stores data in list.
3. In the second view i have same fields with one more note field"notes2" as extra field . All the three fields in this view other than notes2 field should be read-only and should get the data from the view1 when a user opens the form.
4. The user submits the form just filling the notes rest of three fields in 2nd view should be read-only and should have data which is filled in view1.
   Am using InfoPath designer 2010.
   How should i approach on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now if those 2 fields are drop downs in view 1, you should change the control in view 2. Right click a drop down on view 2 and select Change Control. Select Text box.

To make it read only, right click the each of the two fields in view 2 and select text box properties. Under display tab, select Read Only. Those fields will be "Read Only" on view 2.

You can also change the shading of those read only fields to make an effect of "grayed out". Right click the field and select Borders and Shading. Change it on the Shading tab.